# bokeh chart not rendered

Tags: python, bokeh

I have some code I wrote before that successfully rendered charts in bokeh but now the chart is no longer showing up. I simply got the following:

```
GlyphRenderer(  id = '13c54ed8-9ae8-4458-8276-a3dc112c2d73', …)
```

I had already imported bokeh using the following statement:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, gridplot
output_notebook()

BokehJS 0.12.5 successfully loaded.
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I am using a Mac and python 2.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Very* old versions of Bokeh had an option to automatically display plots in in Jupyter notebooks, but this was removed years ago. You need to explicitly call `show` on anything you want to display:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

p = figure()
p.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

show(p)
```